# Ionic 4 production build failing "Error: No component factory found for ComponentPageA, Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?"

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm working in a project with Ionic 4,and in a development env it works just fine (by running `ionic serve`) , nothing is broken, the issue happens when building the app for production by running `ionic build --prod` or `ng build --prod`, and this where things get weird.

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for component_a_page_ComponentAPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
Error: No component factory found for component_a_page_ComponentAPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (main.cec855afb8fb2624fa51.js:1)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (main.cec855afb8fb2624fa51.js:1)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (main.cec855afb8fb2624fa51.js:1)
    at IonRouterOutlet.activateWith (main.cec855afb8fb2624fa51.js:1)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (main.cec855afb8fb2624fa51.js:1)
    at main.cec855afb8fb2624fa51.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (main.cec855afb8fb2624fa51.js:1)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (main.cec855afb8fb2624fa51.js:1)
    at main.cec855afb8fb2624fa51.js:1
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.f4b433f7811f9c421806.js:1)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.f4b433f7811f9c421806.js:1)
    at polyfills.f4b433f7811f9c421806.js:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.f4b433f7811f9c421806.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.cec855afb8fb2624fa51.js:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.f4b433f7811f9c421806.js:1)
    at Zone.runTask (polyfills.f4b433f7811f9c421806.js:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.f4b433f7811f9c421806.js:1)`

I tried updating my packages by running `npm update` and installing new dependencies but still is not working, it says it doesn't find the page component, but in development this work just fine.

These are my dependencies on `package.json`:

`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.0.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.21.4",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.11.10",
    "@types/dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/html2canvas": "0.0.35",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-android": "8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.7",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^7.8.1",
    "ionic": "^5.4.16",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.803.23",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.23",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^8.3.23",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^8.3.23",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.2",
    "@babel/compat-data": "^7.8.6",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.0.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },`

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/entry-components

Comment: @Sébastien Thank you, although it wasn't the direct answer, I read on the docs that it should only the files should have the least amount of code and only the code you need, this doesn't mean you go on the wild and deleting code, but asuring you're using the code you need, I had the Directives and Output decorators without a real use, so by removing these my code started to work again